# What, if any, difference is there between a C# static class and a VB.NET Module

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, roslyn, codedom

C# supports the `static` modifier on a class definition to define a class which cannot be inherited, is sealed, and has only static members. VB.NET supports `Module` statement to define a reference type available through its namespace, to similar effect.

I know that C# and VB.NET share a common CodeDOM, Roslyn compiler, and target IL. My question is what, if any, difference there is between a static class vs. module.

Comment: You can easily out for yourself using any IL inspection tool (like ILSpy). A VB.NET `Module` is nothing more or less than a `sealed` class with `static` members marked with the `StandardModule` attribute. The only remarkable thing is that the class itself is not marked `static` (`abstract sealed` on the IL level), though this makes little difference in practice of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two real differences as far as I am concerned in that a module cannot be inherited nor does it have a constructor.

Aside from that a module is extremely similar to a non-inheritable class where the class only contains shared (vb.net equivalent to static) members.

For example, the following module:

```vb
Public Module Test

    Public Function Foo() As String
        Return "Foo"
    End Function

End Module
```

Can be similarly expressed as:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Test

    Public Shared Function Foo() As String
        Return "Foo"
    End Function

End Class
```

C# developers will likely be more comfortable with the latter whereas legacy Visual Basic developers would go for the former.

Comment: *There are only two real differences as far as I am concerned in that a module ... nor does it have a constructor* - not sure I completely agree that this is a "difference to C#" - both languages have the notion of static constructors/methods that are run automatically in a static context for purposes of initialization; to whit, you can certainly put a `Sub New() Throw New Exception()` in your `Module Module1` and the app will crash upon startup

Comment: @CaiusJard - That is because the starting point of the application is Module1's `New` method. A starting point for the application and a constructor are not the same thing.

Comment: Hmm no, it is because the static constructor will be called upon first reference. The Module1.New is a private, parameterless constructor.

Comment: I think you can prevent the class from being instantiated provide a Private constructor otherwise the default constructor is available.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have said "on startup" as it's slightly misleading/oversimplifying; it's true for when you have `Sub Main` and `Sub New` in Module1. I should have said "on [first reference to anything in module1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/16O37m), which would be [on startup if Main is in module1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oiNjMa)".

Comment: There's one more difference: Routines in a `Module` get pitched into the global namespace (although they may optionally be prefixed with the module name).